# CodeIgniter's is_unique always saying value already exists

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter's form validation, and I've spent a lot of time trying to fix this, with no luck.
I have this field:

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" length="20" placeholder="Username">
```

And I'm using this to validate:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|alpha_dash|is_unique[users.user]');
```

My db has a table `users` and `user` is a field in it, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or what the problem is. The table is empty (but I've also tried with it having records) and in phpmyadmin the "`unique`" icon is selected.
I know the db connection is working fine, because if I remove that rule and enter otherwise valid data and submit the form, then the user is added to the database.

Unless is_unique uses another db configuration file that I haven't configured? I don't really know. It's kind of frustrating and I'm thinking that I may as well just drop the use of a framework...

Your help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: please drop the unique icon and then try

Comment: Nope, still no luck...

Comment: can you post your controller code here http://paste.ofcode.org/ and send the link

Comment: actually in edit form only you got this error ?

Comment: Here it is: http://paste.ofcode.org/33DtgrPX3kfAVkTAiNfGTWm 
I get it when submitting the form, no matter what the input value is.

Comment: can you pls remove the alpha_dash validation and then try..

Comment: Did so, and i got the same outcome, I also now removed all rules except is_unique, and it still doesn't validate :/

Comment: in insert form or in edit form ?

Comment: It is an insert form, for user sign up

Comment: There is a typo in the code you pasted in ofcode.org : `[uses.user]` instead of `[users.user]`. Are you sure the error is triggered by the username field ? What values have you tried to send ?

Comment: @justanelephant actually when u r going to update it,the table still contains old value.

Answer (score 1):

This might/might not help: You seem to be loading the DB **after** running the form validation. There's also a typo `uses.user`.

Answer (score 1):

In Transact-SQL the word "USER" is a special word. Try surrounding uses.user with a back-ticks like so:

```
`users.user`
```

...see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this :-

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|alpha_dash|unique[users.user]');
```

Answer (score 0):

it needs to load database.

```
$this->load->database();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is very old but I just recently encountered a similar problem with a custom form validation and after some serious debugging I found a cause and workaround.

Apparently, the CI core has a small bug: the database library isn't instanced (at least in the latest versions of CI) when calling the `is_unique` form validation method, thus preventing the check from actually being performed and always returning `false` as the validation result.

Here is the workaround for the form validation library (`system/libraries/Form_validation.php`)

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
{
    sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field);

    // add the following line
    $this->CI->load->database();

    return isset($this->CI->db)
        ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0)
        : FALSE;
}
```

By adding the line after the comment, you'll make sure the database library is correctly instanced for the `is_unique` method and you'll get it to work. Without that line, the `isset($this->CI->db)` check will always return false

You could also put that line in the library's constructor, but then you'd be instancing the database library in all form validation rules which is not necessary (only `is_unique` needs it).

Answer (score 0):

Using your code as an example, the `is_unique` validation rule works by looking for a field called `user_name` in your users database table. If the field with the same value exists it validates as false.

To make sure it runs only when the user submits a new value, you could check the posted value `$this->input->post('user_name')` against the value you pulled from the database to populate your form with. If they are the same, don't validate `is_unique`:

```
if($this->input->post('user_name') != $original_value) {
   $is_unique =  '|is_unique[users.user_name]'
} else {
   $is_unique =  ''
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean'.$is_unique);
```